# How to check if value is bigger than each other value?

Tags: mysql

I need to check if one value is bigger than each of other values.

Currently I have this query but it only check if the value is bigger than all of total other values:

```
IF (SELECT SUM(`price`) AS '14' 
    from data 
    where sale = 14) > (
        SELECT SUM(`price`) AS 'x14' 
        from data where sale != 14)
THEN SET New.price=1.99;
```

While I need it to check if sale's(14)-related is bigger than (15) and bigger than (16)..

Comment: find greatest value and then compare with that

Comment: What is the structure of your tables and what columns do want to select?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan this is a great idea. I will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//DECLARE  price_1 and 2 first 

SELECT SUM(`price`) INTO price_1  from data where sale = 14 ;
SELECT MAX(price_others) INTO max_price FROM 
( 
  SELECT SUM(`price`) as price_others, sale  FROM data 
  where sale != 14 GROUP BY sale 
) TMP ;

IF price_1 > max_price THEN 
  SET New.price=1.99;
END IF ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it was useful but I don't feel it is practical in case all has same statements like this: IF price_1 > price_2 THEN 
  SET New.price=1.99;
END IF ;
IF price_1 > price_3 THEN 
  SET New.price=1.99;
END IF ;
IF price_1 > price_4 THEN 
  SET New.price=1.99;
END IF ;....

Comment: So I wanted to group in somehow IF price_1 > price_2 and > price_3 and >price_4